# Why create constants from props and state in react?

Tags: reactjs

I see this code pattern a lot in React code:

```
render() {
  const units = this.props.units;
  const temperature = this.state.temperature;

  return (<p>{temperature} {units}</p>);
}
```

and some developers I've asked say that its standard practice to pull state/props into local constants before using them in render or other functions - however, I can't find this practice discussed anywhere in the React docs, and the example code in those docs sometimes just access state/prop attributes directly.

I would prefer to use direct access because it makes the code more readable when you can immediately see where attributes are coming from instead of having to hunt down the local constant definitions.

Before I make this decision though, I was wondering if anyone knew why this practice exists and if there are good reasons to use it?

Is there a functional difference between the example above and this?

```
render() {
  return (<p>{this.state.temperature} {this.props.units}</p>);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a standard practice to pull state/props when there a MANY props/state that are going to be used inside your functions

```
eg: const { prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, ... } = this.props
    const { state1, state2, state3, ... } = this.state
```

You can now reference them with the const names instead of

```
this.props.propName/stateName everywhere.
```

You shouldn't do that in the example you provided where there is just 1/few props/state

```
const units = this.props.units; // Not recommended
```

**Bottomline : Just cleaner code. Matter of preference.**

Answer (score 1):

The reason why we need to get constants from props is to destructure the props object. Destructuring means your getting a property of the props object. With that you can lessen the code needed instead of using this.props.yourProps when you destructure it. It wil only be yourProps instead.

Also your destructure should be on es6 for es6 standards: Use

```
 const {units} = this.props; //This gets the key units from the props object (es6 Syntax)
```

Instead of

```
const units = this.props.units; // This does the same but without using the es6 syntax
```

If you Structure your code in this manner you can write less code and can maintain it better... When we follow standards like this we won't worry even the organization switches from one developer to another.